# align \sim like equal signs in equation modus

Tags: equations, align

I want to align a `\sim` like an equal sign in an equation environment. Is there an easy way to make Latex recognize the `\sim` like an equal sign?

```
 \begin{equation}
        \begin{aligned}
       Z \sim N(0,1)  \\
     \epsilon \sim N(0,0.25) \\
        X_{i} =  \epsilon Z 2^{3}
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
```

Thanks

Comment: Just add the alignment character `&` before the `\sim` and the `=`: `\begin{aligned}
       Z &\sim N(0,1)  \\
     \epsilon &\sim N(0,0.25) \\
        X_{i} &=  \epsilon Z 2^{3}
    \end{aligned}`.

Comment: Use `&\sim` for each line. If you don't mark the alignment points with an `&`, the equations will be aligned by the last character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
Z           & \sim N(0,1)       \\
\epsilon    & \sim N(0,0.25)    \\
X_{i}       & = \epsilon Z 2^{3}
\end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
 \end{document}
```

[image]